eas update command throws an error: Expected Metro server instance to have private functions exposed
After updating the expo SDK to Ver.51, I keep getting the following error after running eas update on Windows:
Error: Expected Metro server instance to have private functions exposed.
[expo-cli]     at forkMetroBuildAsync (C:\PATH_TO_MY_APP\node_modules@expo\cli\src\export\fork-bundleAsync.ts:287:11)
[expo-cli]     at buildAsync (C:\PATH_TO_MY_APP\node_modules@expo\cli\src\export\fork-bundleAsync.ts:207:31)
[expo-cli]     at async Promise.all (index 0)
[expo-cli]     at bundleProductionMetroClientAsync (C:\PATH_TO_MY_APP\node_modules@expo\cli\src\export\fork-bundleAsync.ts:224:12)
[expo-cli]     at createBundlesAsync (C:\PATH_TO_MY_APP\node_modules@expo\cli\src\export\fork-bundleAsync.ts:86:19)
[expo-cli]     at exportAppAsync (C:\PATH_TO_MY_APP\node_modules@expo\cli\src\export\exportApp.ts:92:19)
[expo-cli]     at exportAsync (C:\PATH_TO_MY_APP\node_modules@expo\cli\src\export\exportAsync.ts:19:3)

On top of that, the app no longer hot-reloads after updating some content.

However, eas build works well, I can see my builds on the Dev dashboard.


What I have been trying to do:

I ran npx expo-doctor and npx expo install --check
Delete the node_modules folder and package-lock then run again npm i
eas logout then eas login
Install the latest expo-cli

Nothing worked, what did I miss?

I had same issue after upgrading to SDK 51
For me the fixes were:

Removing "resolutions" and "overrides" from "package.json"
Removing "expo-router/babel" plugin from "babel.config.js"


I deleted what you mentioned and deleted the node_modules, then npm i. it worked. I do not know why expo updates always break stuff down.
